# Print a row of database by foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I use codeigniter. I want print rows name of database by `foreach`. is not array value row name in the database.

My way don't work and is output: `Array`

In the Controller:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM welcome ORDER BY id desc");

$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
$data['output'] = array('name' => $row->name);
}
$data['output'] = $data;

$this -> load -> view('welcome', $data);
```

In the view:

```
<?=$output?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put as your example, but queries should be in model:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM welcome ORDER BY id desc");

$data = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $data['output'][] = $row->name;
}
$this -> load -> view('welcome', $data);
```

In the view:

```
<pre>
<?=print_r($output)?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$output` is an array of values, so to print it out, you need to use a function such as `print_r()`.

```
<?php

print_r($output);

?>
```

Using `echo` or the PHP short output tags on an array will output the data type `Array` instead of it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `<?=$output?>` to see arrays.

Arrays are structured variables that are composed of multiple keys and values.

That way you should use either:

print_r() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

or

var_dump() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print your array, display it all with this:

```
foreach ($output as $stuff)  {

   print_r($stuff);
   /* and a break like */
   /* in care your array is multidimensional */

}
```